# Create Amazon SQS backup automatically in another queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm wondering is there is a way to create 2 Amazon SQS queues: 1 for the main activity and the other for backup?

Is there a way to make the first queue send every received message to another SQS queue automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "backup" an Amazon SQS queue.

However, if you configure the source system to send the message to an Amazon SNS topic, then **multiple Amazon SQS queues can subscribe to the Amazon SNS topic**.

[image: SNS to SQS fan-out]

When doing this, I recommend you use [raw message delivery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html) to ensure that the message content remains the same after passing through Amazon SNS.

See:

- [How to Send Fanout Event Notifications – Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/send-fanout-event-notifications/)
- [Common Amazon SNS Scenarios - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-common-scenarios.html)